# Implementations registered with Simple Injector's RegisterCollection are not decorated

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I have a constructor (`AnimalHandler`) that takes two slightly different implementations of the same interface (`IAnimal`). Using Simple Injector, how can I automatically decorate both implementations?

The chronology of an example:

```
interface IAnimal {
  string Speak();
}
class Cat : IAnimal{
  public string Speak() => "Meow";
}
class Dog : IAnimal{
  public string Speak() => "Woof";
}
class AnimalSpeakLoudlyDecorator : IAnimal {
  private readonly IAnimal _decorated;
  public AnimalSpeakLoudlyDecorator(IAnimal decorated) {
    _decorated = decorated;
  }
  public string Speak() => _decorated.Speak().ToUpper();
}
class AnimalHandler {
  private readonly Cat _cat;
  private readonly Dog _dog;
  public AnimalHandler(Cat cat, Dog dog) {
    _cat = cat;
    _dog = dog;
  }
  public string HandleCat() => _cat.Speak();
  public string HandleDog() => _dog.Speak();
}
```

Here I realize that interfaces should be used in the constructor so that decoration could occur. I thusly create `AnimalInterfaceHandler`, `ICat`, and `IDog`:

```
interface ICat : IAnimal { }
interface IDog : IAnimal { }
class Cat : ICat {...}
class Dog : IDog {...}
class AnimalInterfaceHandler {
  private readonly ICat _cat;
  private readonly IDog _dog;
  public AnimalInterfaceHandler(ICat cat, IDog dog) {
    _cat = cat;
    _dog = dog;
  }
  public string HandleCat() => _cat.Speak();
  public string HandleDog() => _dog.Speak();
}
```

I [register multiple interfaces with the same implementation](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#register-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-implementation).

```
var container = new Container();
var catRegistration = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<Cat>(container);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(ICat), catRegistration);
var dogRegistration = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<Dog>(container);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(IDog), dogRegistration);
container.RegisterCollection<IAnimal>(new[] { catRegistration, dogRegistration });
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IAnimal), typeof(AnimalSpeakLoudlyDecorator), Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Verify();
var handler = container.GetInstance<AnimalInterfaceHandler>();
Assert.AreEqual("MEOW", handler.HandleCat());
```

The assert fails; the decorator is not applied despite being `IAnimal` being registered with `RegisterCollection`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var container = new Container();

container.RegisterConditional<IAnimal, Cat>(c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "cat");
container.RegisterConditional<IAnimal, Dog>(c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "dog");

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IAnimal), typeof(AnimalSpeakLoudlyDecorator));

container.Verify();
```

This registration makes use of the `RegisterConditional` method, which allows to make a conditional or contextual registration based on information about the consumer. In this case it uses the name of the constructor argument it is injected into.

Comment: It seems a *touch* brittle, but `.Verify()` should alert me if/when I refactor `Cat` to, say, `CatBase`. While your answer does solve my non-toy problem, is it expected behavior for decorators to not apply to `RegisterCollection`, particularly in the case of implementations with multiple interfaces? Thanks very much, SI is a fantastic library!

Comment: I would probably choose your `RegisterConditional` solution over my hacky `RegisterCollection` anyway because it means I don't have to create `ICat` and `IDog`. Kinda silly that I must create an interface to mark each concrete implementation.